# Is it possible to limit data in a ksqlDB table?

Tags: caching, ksqldb

I want to implement a materialized cache using `ksqlDB` because I need to update the cache as soon as data is written in the main database.

The write workflow is:

1. Data is written into `Postgres`;
2. Data is written from `Postgres` to `Kafka` with the help of `Debezium` (change data capture);
3. `ksqlDB` uses `STREAM` to read data from `Kafka`;
4. `ksqlDB` updates a `TABLE` so that new data is cached;
5. Later, a backend reads the data from `TABLE`.

In my case `TABLE` will have a column `userId` and some payload in other columns.

The problem is, the number of rows in `TABLE` will soon become too large to be stored (the data is denormalized so keeping it all on disk/memory is not practical). I guess one could use `SQL`'s `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to store only the most recent data, although I am not sure if it is possible in `ksqlDB`. Anyway, it won't help in my case as I would like to store at least `N` most recent rows for each user.

Is `ksqlDB` capable to do what I need?

Comment: How big a dataset are you envisioning? Is this a theoretical limit you're forecasting or you've hit up against it already?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt it is a theoretical limit, let's say 10,000,000 users where each has 100,000 rows. In most cases only the most recent 100 to 200 rows will be used by each user.